# how to parse string in to two values in shell script

Tags: shell, parsing

I am new to shell script and i want to parse the following strings in shell script:

```
aspj-arch-bpm-oracle-11.1.1.7-6.2.1.10000.jar
aspj-arch-ecm-oracle-wcc-11.1.1.7-6.2.1.10000.jar
aspj-arch-rules-opa-10.4.2-server-6.0.2.10000.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

here i want to read all the strings and i need two values.

```
value1 = aspj-arch-bpm-oracle-11.1.1.7
value2 = 6.2.1.10000
```

and .jar should be removed.

here i can read all the strings by using for loop

```
for i in *
do
echo "$i"
done
```

but here i want insted of printing the string i want two values like this

```
for i in *
do 
value1= "some caommand"
value2= "some command"
echo $value1
echo $value2
done.
```

how can i do this by using shell script.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on the rules that you want to apply? It seems that in the single example that you gave there is a rule at work, split on the first `-` inside the version number(?), but this extrapolation (you just gave the example without a single word of comment!) does not apply to the other input lines you showed us.  Maybe someone else could help anyway, but for sure I can't... PS if your question were not clarified, it would deserve a down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for this:

```
while read line; do 
    value1=${line%-*.jar}
    value2=${line##*-}
    value2=${value2%.jar}

    echo "Value 1: $value1"
    echo "Value 2: $value2"
done < input_file.txt
```

For your provided input, this gives:

```
Value 1: aspj-arch-bpm-oracle-11.1.1.7
Value 2: 6.2.1.10000
Value 1: aspj-arch-ecm-oracle-wcc-11.1.1.7
Value 2: 6.2.1.10000
Value 1: aspj-arch-rules-opa-10.4.2-server
Value 2: 6.0.2.10000
Value 1: spring-webmvc-portlet
Value 2: 3.0.5.RELEASE
```

You could also use `sed` if you wanted to obtain `value2` in a single command:

```
value2=$(sed 's/.*-\(.*\).jar/\1/g' <<< $line)
```